# frame changes are discarded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

i am trying to rePosition a when resizing another using some changes on these views' frames
the changes are made successfully but the problem is that these changes are discarded (undone) and the views get their old frames back.
changing frames code bellow

```
viewHolder.frame = CGRectMake(viewHolder.frame.origin.x,viewHolder.frame.origin.y, viewHolder.frame.size.width, viewHolder.frame.size.height + 30);
CGRect frame3 = CGRectMake(belowView.frame.origin.x, belowView.frame.origin.y + 30, belowView.frame.size.width, belowView.frame.size.height);
belowView.frame = frame3;
```

so can someone tell me why is that happening here?

Comment: you'll have to show more code, it sounds like you may be setting translatesautoresizingmask, setting contraints and then tryign to set a frame

Comment: Actually no ... This is all of my code I am calling in viewDidLoad (the view is initialized from nib file )